# Looping and assigning values from the list inside a list until empty

Tags: python, list

I have the lists inside a list:

```
row_column_values = [['0', '0', 'proba1'],
                     ['0', '0', 'proba1'],
                     ['0', '0', 'proba1'], ...]
```

I want my loop to go through every 3 elements from the lists inside a list, assign it to the 'row, column, value' elements, and then take another 3 elements and assign it and repeat until empty. For now it only takes first three elements.

```
for list in row_column_values:
    while True:
        for line in range(len(list)):
            row = int(row_column_values[0][0])
            column = int(row_column_values[0][1])
            value = row_column_values[0][2]
            memory[row][column] = value
        else:
            break
```

Comment: what output are you getting, vs what is the expected output?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in class with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `row_column_values[0]` every time through the loop, not the current row of the iteration.

There's no need for the inner loop at all.

```
for line in row_column_values:
    row = int(line[0])
    column = int(line[1])
    memory[row][column] = line[2]
```

Comment: Thanks!! I spent like 3 hours on it